# Echo array inside foreach and if isset but only show one data for each value

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, foreach

So I have this list of array (I changed the values for privacy purpose);

```
$datalist  = array(
1 => 
array(
     "12.2.2.2",
     "Netherlands 1",
     "Hub 1",
     "Password",
     "Mfalse"
) ,
array(
    "12.2.2.2",
    "Singapore 1",
    "Hub 2",
    "Password 2",
    "Mfalse"
)
```

And I want the output of array[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL6ES.png) which is the 'Hub' and 'Hub 2'. So I did this php code since I want it to be looped inside a table so all the details will be tabled and organized. But the only thing I need for now is the HUB to be shown.

```
                foreach ($response->monitors as $monitors) {
                    if(isset($monitors->id)){
                      echo
                      '<tr>
                      <td><i class="fas fa-globe"></i> '.$monitors->friendly_name.'</td>';
                           foreach ($datalist as $key => $value) {
                            # code...
                            if (isset($key)) {
                               echo '<td>'.$value[2].'</td>';
                            }
                        }
                      echo '<td>'.$monitors->url.'</td>
                      <td>'.$monitors->status.'</td>
                      </tr>';
                    }
                  }
```

Since i'm also using other value outputs and the array I wanted is also inside another foreach loop for the table.

So the main problem lies in this part, since whenever I use this, it outputs like this on each loop of the table

```
foreach ($datalist as $key => $value) {
                        # code...
                        if (isset($key)) {
                           echo '<td>'.$value[2].'</td>';
                        }
                    }
```

Output:

```
Netherlands 1 Hub 1 Hub 2 12.2.2.2 
Singapore   1 Hub 1 Hub 2 12.2.2.2
```

But the desired output i'm looking for is;

```
Netherlands 1 Hub 1 12.2.2.2 
Singapore   1 Hub 2 12.2.2.2
```

What could be wrong in my array statement for foreach?

var_dump of $datalist

```
array (
1 => 
array (
 0 => 'x',
 1 => 'Netherlands 1',
 2 => 'PeenoiseSync',
 3 => 'x',
 4 => 'Mfalse',
),
2 => 
array (
 0 => 'x',
 1 => 'Singapore 1',
 2 => 'PeenoiseSync',
 3 => 'x',
 4 => 'Mfalse',
),
3 => 
array (
 0 => 'x',
 1 => 'Singapore 2',
 2 => 'PeenoiseSync',
 3 => 'x',
 4 => 'Mfalse',
),
 4 => 
 array (
  0 => 'x',
  1 => 'Singapore 3',
  2 => 'PeenoiseSync',
  3 => 'x',
  4 => 'Mfalse',
 ),
 5 => 
 array (
  0 => 'x',
  1 => 'Singapore 4',
  2 => 'PeenoiseSync',
  3 => 'x',
  4 => 'Mfalse',
 ),
 6 => 
 array (
  0 => 'x',
  1 => 'Singapore 5',
  2 => 'PeenoiseSync',
  3 => 'x',
  4 => 'Mfalse',
 ),
 7 => 
 array (
  0 => 'x',
  1 => 'Singapore 6',
  2 => 'PeenoiseSync',
  3 => 'x',
  4 => 'Mfalse',
 ),
 8 => 
 array (
  0 => 'x',
  1 => 'Singapore 7',
  2 => 'YTAC',
  3 => 'x',
  4 => 'Mfalse',
 ),
)
```

Updated again: Desired output should be something similar to this;
[image: Desired output]

Output i'm getting;
[image: Output i'm getting]

Comment: $monitors->friendly_name what do this outputs?

Comment: @AlbertoVidales i'm using uptime robot api that outputs some name like SG-1 and etc.

Comment: My question is, does that variable is the same as position 1 value in your arrays?

Comment: Please `var_dump($datalist);` and post the result so we can see how it is _actually_ constructed.  You can X-out certain values if you need to, but don't try hand-writing the entire thing.  That _always_ goes badly and leads to providing poor information.

Comment: @PatrickQ added the var dump of the $datalist;

Comment: You seem to have censored the one value you say you care about. Please give us something that we can use to provide a result that you will accept. You should update with values for the 3rd elements in the sub-arrays, and also provide the desired output that corresponds to the updated `$datalist`.

Comment: Alright I fixed it one more time. I added the details for the hub names and added a picture of the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes that your `$datalist` array is in the same order as your `$monitors` array and contains the same number of elements.  You simply need to keep track of which monitor you're on, and then use the same index to access the corresponding `$datalist` row.  You do this by setting `as $index=>$monitors` and then using `$datalist[$index][2]`

```
// re-indexing $datalist since in your example it is not 0-indexed
$datalist = array_values($datalist);
foreach ($response->monitors as $index=>$monitors) {
    if(isset($monitors->id)){
        echo
            '<tr>
             <td><i class="fas fa-globe"></i> '.$monitors->friendly_name.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$datalist[$index][2].'</td>';

        echo '<td>'.$monitors->url.'</td>
            <td>'.$monitors->status.'</td>
            </tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Is a good approach indeed, but this can lead to messy relational data in case that they are not in the same order.

Comment: @AlbertoVidales That was the point of my preamble. If they're not in the same order, then OP is up a creek, as there seems to be no identifying shared value between the records.

Comment: seems pretty easy to find out if he´s going to be able to do what he wants, just need to know exactly what $monitors has (just one item) so we can tell what to compare in order to help him out, but well, I'll leave it until here.

Comment: Its almost working but there's a blank record on the first value sadly. I'll just fiddle with it and see what I can do. Thank you!

Comment: $monitors has a lot of data but i'm mostly using 3-4 data;

`"id": 777749809,
"friendly_name": "Google",
"url": "http://www.google.com"
"status": 1,`

Taken from uptimerobot api.

Comment: @Sync The `$datalist` provided in your question is missing the `[0]` index. This is quite odd for a numerically-indexed array.  However, you can simply run `$datalist = array_values($datalist);` to resolve this.  I'll update my answer to reflect.

Comment: @Sync Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You miss an " after password 2

```
$datalist  = array(
1 => 
array(
     "12.2.2.2",
     "Netherlands 1",
     "Hub 1",
     "Password",
     "Mfalse"
) ,
array(
    "12.2.2.2",
    "Singapore 1",
    "Hub 2",
    "Password 2",
    "Mfalse"
)
);

foreach ($datalist as $key => $value) {
                        # code...
                        if (isset($key)) {
                           echo '<td>'.$value[2].'</td>';
                        }
                    }
```

test here

http://phpfiddle.org

Comment: Oh sorry that was my mistake when I was editing the code, but the actual code has that ". I'll fix it right up.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a variable to compare from $monitors against $value[1] since is going to output all arrays information in $datalist per $monitors iteration, I'm leaving an example on how you can solve this, but in order to help you further I will need to know what $monitors->friendly_name exactly outputs and what you have in the $monitors variable (maybe there's something we can use to compare and match your $datalist array corresponding to the correct monitor:

```
foreach ($datalist as $key => $value) {
    # code...
    if ($monitors->friendly_name == $value[1]) {
        echo '<td>'.$value[2].'</td>';
    }
```

Assuming that $key is always set (I don't think foreach will not set the $key in an iteration), this will output the value matching the correct array value for that specific monitor

Comment: $monitors is used by another api i'm calling which is not a part of the array i'm trying to output. The $monitors is working properly as expected, only the arrays are having an issue, maybe because of my argument for the loop or something.

Comment: I do know you don't have control over the monitors data, just try to find a variable where you can compare from $monitors agains each of your array elements, in this case if the values are the same it will output the proper data related to that monitor, if not it just go into the next until it finds it, once is true remember to leave your foreach so you don't waste resources after is found.